# I have a problem with understanding var. Can someone please explain me?

Tags: javascript

I have one problem in understanding hoisting.

```js
console.log(name);
var name = 'klaudia';

console.log(name2);
var name2 = 'alicja';
```

In var name2 I have undefined instead of string but I don't know why.

[image]

Comment: You have `undefined` for the first log aswell

Comment: The variable declaration is hosted, but the initialization remains where it is.

Comment: For testing in e.g. console, please remember, that `var` allows redeclarations, and that `window.name` is an existing variable in a browser context. Just as a few glass-ball ideas towards how misconceptions might arise.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

Comment: @ASDFGerte First log shows normally, only the second one has undefined. Please look on the photo.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee already did it. Still cant find the answer for my question. I want to know why in first var everything works well and in second i have undefined.

Comment: `name` is [an alias](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) for `window.name`, hence its available in global scope

Comment: Why these logs show is not explainable from the code you have shown. As mentioned, there are ideas where an unintended value may come from, but it cannot be determined unless you show more than just that code (e.g. html and whatever else may influence the site, like other javascript).

Comment: But the rest is empty. i only created html with default head and empty body (only with sript src to js file). I have already checked it on several browsers and it works the same.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var name = 'klaudia';
console.log(name);


var name2 = 'alicja';
console.log(name2);
```